# A question regarding the convergence of a sequence of functions at some point on $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, the-baire-space

***Problem***:  Does there exist a sequence of continuous functions $ f_n:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1  f_n(x) dx=0$ but their doesn't exist any $x \in [0,1]$ for which the sequence $ f_n(x)$ converges?

***My approach***:  Actually, I think the above assertion can be proven false. Rather we can show that for some $\alpha \in [0,1]$, the sequence converges to $0.$ If that doesn't happen, then, for each $\alpha \in [0,1]$, there exists an infinite subsequence of $f_n(\alpha)$ such that $\| f_n(\alpha) \| \geq 1/k$, then define $S_k=\{\alpha \in [0,1] | f_n(\alpha)| \geq 1/k$ for infinitely many $n$ $\}$, then $S_k$ is a nested sequence and I think as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=0$ then closure of $S_k$ has an empty interior .

But the collection $S_k$ may not be closed . Though the union of these collection gives the whole space $[0,1]$ but  it is Baire space, then some contradiction may arise.
Any help is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Just take
$$
f_n(x) = \sin(2\pi x + n)
$$
Then all the $f_n$ are continuous, $∫_0^1 f_n = 0$ but $f_n(x)$ never converges for whatever $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: But, in your answer, the range space of the sequence of functions $f_n$ is not $[0,\infty)$